# SQL Server transaction with NodeJS

Tags: node.js, sql-server, transactions, type-conversion, check-constraints

In my application I am using SQL Server and doing a sequence of database operations. For that I am using a transaction.

After the transaction is started, I got a data type validation error. I am not throwing the error or rolling back the transaction since I have to do some more database operations, but then I am getting aborted with an error

> Transaction has not begun. Call begin() first.

I'm not able to do any other database operations within that transaction.

But in the same scenario, if I am getting a check constraint violation error then I am not getting the error and could able to proceed with the other operations.

What can be the reason? Is there any difference with the data type check error and check constraint error? Anyone please help....

Thanks
Saumya

Comment: Do you have any specific code and error messages to report? Otherwise it's all very suppositional. Have a read through, [How to create a Minimal, Reproducible Example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example)